# Understanding the strong Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I have problems to understand the strong Markov property (Klenke, p. 356):

> Let $I \subset [0,\infty)$ be closed under addition. A Markov process $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ with distributions $(\mathbf{P}_x, x \in E)$ has the strong Markov property if, for every a.s. finite stopping time $\tau$, every bounded $\mathcal{B}(E)^{\otimes I}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable function $f : E^I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and every $x \in E$, we have 
>     $$\mathbf{E}_x\Bigl[f\bigl((X_{\tau+t})_{t\in I}\bigr) \big| \mathcal{F}_\tau \Bigr] = \mathbf{E}_{X_\tau}\Bigl[f(X)\Bigr] := \int_{E^I} \kappa(X_\tau, dy) f(y)\, .$$

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ can this formulation be simplified?

And in general, is there an easier formulation somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $E_x((X_{\tau+t})_{t \in I} | \mathcal{F}_{\tau})$? How do you define a conditional expectation of a family of random variables?

Comment: @saz: mmh... that doesn't work...

Comment: @saz: Please help!!! I'm not understanding anything about this definition.

Comment: Although it is probably entirely evident to you what part of this definition you do understand (and what needs illustration or explanation), you have given your Readers little hint as to where the line is drawn.  The choice of $I$, for example, is motivated by its use as an index set of "times".  Is that clear?  Please narrow down your concern about the definition and its understanding.